# WebSphere ND 8.5.5.15 - SpringBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE - App installed, started, but i am not able to reach it

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-8

I am a new WebSphere/SpringBoot user. I have a bare-bone **Spring Boot application(v2.1.8.RELEASE)**, war file built using **Gradle 5.6.2**, from **STS 3.9.9.RELEASE**, that is running well on my localhost/tomcat, where i only call localhost:8080/hi, and the app says hi.

I then proceeded to install it on **WAS ND 8.5.5.15**, on a profile/node/server, that is pointing to Java 8, and it was started successfully. **But i am unable to reach the URL, when i entered it from the browser(Can't reach the page) or from postman(Could not get any response). That is the only application installed in that node/server.**

Some other details are:
(1) Another URL, using the same ip, but sitting on another profile/node, is reachable, so it is not an ip issue.
(2) The port 9082 is correct as per serverindex.xml:

```
<specialEndpoints xmi:id="NamedEndPoint_1568009064531" endPointName="WC_defaulthost">
<endPoint xmi:id="EndPoint_1568009064531" host="*" port="9082"/>
</specialEndpoints>
```

(3) The context root is correct as per Web Module properties/Context Root For Web Modules.
(4) The *"*hi end-point*"* is correctly "configured" in the application as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HelloBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
return application.sources(HelloBootApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(HelloBootApplication.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/hi")
public String sayHello() {
return "Hiiii";
}
}
```

(5) The WEB-INF/web.xml in the installedApps, is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"/>
```

Where else could i look to pin-point the issue?
Thanks in advance.

P.S Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but after playing around, i managed to get it to work.

2 things i did differently(but i am not sure if this was the reason it worked):
- I made sure the server is always stopped, before installing/ uninstalling the app. (I did not care about the node/node agent, as there was only 1).
- I ran the server in development mode(highly unlikely to solve the issue, as i unchecked the development mode afterwards and it was still working, although that was the last thing i played with, before it worked...)